# How can I set the title of the Navigation bar title using Navigation View in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
Ext.define('MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    alias: 'widget.myview',

    config: {                
        title: 'My View',
        items: [            
            {
                id: 'alist',
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: [
                    '<div>{DisplayName}</div>'
                ],
                onItemDisclosure: true
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Currently the initial navigation view has no title set even though I've specified it in config. Is this a bug? I realise when you push a new view, it will use the title of the view to populate, but I need the title set initially before any views have been pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alist` item IS the first view, give it a title and you should be good. The nav view takes it's title from the currently active item.